# Issuing update to Solr makes Duplicates

Tags: php, database, solr, full-text-search

I just started using Solr 6.0 the other day, and had a script made for updating Solr index via a php script using curl. 
But right now, there are duplicate entries when updated with the php script below.

The schema right now is like this: id (unique key field), url, keywords, description, title.

Is this because I did not specify a explicit unique key field on url with the schema?

I would like to have the url as a unique key so it will prevent from Solr to index duplicates upon update, and overwrite if it is a duplicate. How do you do this?

```
<?php
// apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-curl


// curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?fieldnames=url,keywords,description,title&commit=true' -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8' --data-binary @$file


$SOLR_SERVER = '127.0.0.1';
$CORE = 'core1';
ob_start();
$callback = &$_REQUEST['fd-callback'];
$url = 'http://'. $SOLR_SERVER .':8983/solr/'. $CORE .'/update/csv?fieldnames=url,keywords,description,title&commit=true';

if (!empty($_FILES['fd-file']) and is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fd-file']['tmp_name'])) {
    $name = $_FILES['fd-file']['name'];
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['fd-file']['tmp_name']);
} else {
    $name = urldecode(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']);
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
}

$header = array("Content-type:text/csv; charset=utf-8");
$post = $data;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); 
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($ch) {
    $output = 'Upload Success!';
}else {
    $output = 'Upload did not work!';
}

// $opt = &$_REQUEST['upload_option'];
// isset($opt) and $output .= "\nReceived upload_option with value $opt";
if ($callback) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $output = addcslashes($output, "\\\"\0..\x1F");
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><script type="text/javascript">',
       "try{window.top.$callback(\"$output\")}catch(e){}</script></body></html>";
} else {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    echo $output;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the URL to identify a document uniquely, define the url field as your uniqueKey. If you have an `id` field defined as your uniqueKey, but submit identical URLs with different ids, Solr cannot know that these documents are the same object.

Another option is to use the `id` field to actually reference a unique URL, either as hash or from your DB.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is it possible to use the SchemaAPI to change the uniqueKey? I tried curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{ "add-field" : { "name":"url", "type":"string", "stored":true, "uniqueKey":true}}' http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/schema but it didn't work.

Comment: No, that's not currently possible: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7242 - you could duplicate 'url' to your 'id' field to hack around it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much MatsLindh,

I've figured out how to do it.

First, I changed:

```
 $url = 'http://'. $SOLR_SERVER .':8983/solr/'. $CORE .'/update/csv?fieldnames=url,keywords,description,title&commit=true';
```

To:

```
$url = 'http://'. $SOLR_SERVER .':8983/solr/'. $CORE .'/update/csv?fieldnames=id,keywords,description,title&commit=true';
```

and added

```
<copyField source="id" dest="url"/>
```

under

```
  <field name="description" type="strings"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="keywords" type="strings"/>
  <field name="title" type="strings"/>
  <field name="url" type="strings"/>
```

in managed-schema .

I used the copyField to copy id to url as you suggested. 
It's working fine now, and the duplicates are not shown.

So, what changed is, I made the uploader update the url into id, and used copyField to copy it to the url field.